# Realistic turns for vehicle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add realistic looking driving behavior to a simple vehicle. Currently I use the rigidbody MovePosition, and I only apply MoveRotation when I have detected forward/reverse axis from Input.

Instead I would like to apply direction/rotation even if the car is coasting, but do not want it turning when standing still, as if it were a tracked vehicle. I would also like the turn to appear to come from the front of the vehicle where the wheels (not actual objects in the game) would be located.

What I have so far is mostly borrowed from the tanks tutorial:

```
m_MovementInputValue = Input.GetAxis(m_MovementAxisName);
    m_TurnInputValue = Input.GetAxis(m_TurnAxisName);

    // Create a vector in the direction the tank is facing with a magnitude based on the input, speed and the time between frames.
    Vector3 movement = transform.forward * m_MovementInputValue * m_Speed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Apply this movement to the rigidbody's position.
    m_Rigidbody.MovePosition(m_Rigidbody.position + movement);

    if (m_MovementInputValue > 0)
    {
        float turn = m_TurnInputValue * m_TurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Make this into a rotation in the y axis.
        Quaternion turnRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, turn, 0f);

        // Apply this rotation to the rigidbody's rotation.
        m_Rigidbody.MoveRotation(m_Rigidbody.rotation * turnRotation);    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can save yourself some time by looking at the Wheel Collider components of Unity API : http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelCollider.html  , I saw a demo some times ago which used it to make a full racing game so it should do the trick to simulate realistic vehicles ([Demo in question](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351)).

Other than that here is how you *could* do it :

For starters if you want your vehicle to turn only when it is moving forward or backward you can multiply your *turn* force by the *velocity forward vector* of your vehicle

```
float turn = m_TurnInputValue * m_TurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime * (m_Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude / MaxVehicleSpeed);
```

The idea of *(m_Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude / MaxVehicleSpeed)* is to have a value between 0 and 1 depending on the vehicle speed.

then for the turn to appear from the front of the vehicle you need to change your point of rotation, and I can't find a solution using *MoveRotation*. You can do that by using the *AddForceAtPosition* function of the *Rigidbody* but it'll become more complicated to compute it.

Here is the idea :

```
Vector3 force = transform.right * turn;
m_Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(force, MiddleOfWheelAxis);
```

With *MiddleOfWheelAxis* the point between your two front wheels.

Comment: I played with wheel colliders, but it was more complex than what I am looking for. I may try it again

As to the rest, thank you. The only thing I don't get is velocity.forward. Was that deprecated in Unity 5?

Comment: Sorry I was saying the forward component of the velocity vector, but it doesn't make a lot of sense. magnitude / maxSpeed seems to be more apropriate, I'll update my post.